# File says it downloaded in log, but not in local directrory

Tags: command-line, ftp, winscp

I am using WinSCP to automate a get from an FTP server. The log shows me that the file was downloaded to the directory I specified but it's not in the directory.

This is the Scheduler param.

```
    /log="C:\TEST\Automation\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /command "open 
sftp://HIDDEN:NOTTHATDUMB@ftplocation.com/  -rawsettings TryAgent=0 
AuthGSSAPI=0" "put C:\TEST\Automation\*.pgp  -nopreservetime -nopermissions" 
"get /Inbox/* C:\TEST\Automation\NewFolder"  "exit"
```

The log reads as if the file was downloaded but cant find file.

Log Output:

```
 > 2018-05-23 12:07:50.077 Script: get /Inbox/* C:\TEST\Automation\NewFolder
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.077 Listing directory "/Inbox".
> 2018-05-23 12:07:50.077 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 15, Number: 523
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.155 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 10, Number: 523
> 2018-05-23 12:07:50.155 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 10, Number: 780
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.233 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 164, Number: 780
> 2018-05-23 12:07:50.233 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 10, Number: 1036
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 50, Number: 1036
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 Status code: 1
> 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 10, Number: 1284
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 FILENAME.txt;-;163487;2018-05-23T16:06:50.000Z;3;"200" [200];"100" [100];rw-------;0
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T05:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 Copying 1 files/directories to local directory "C:\Test\Automation\" - total size: 163,487
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: NewFolder
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 File: '/Inbox/FILENAME.txt' [2018-05-23T16:06:50.000Z] [163487]
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 Copying "/Inbox/FILENAME.txt" to local directory started.
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 Checking existence of partially transferred file.
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 Opening remote file.
> 2018-05-23 12:07:50.280 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 54, Number: 1539
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.327 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 40, Number: 1284
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.327 Discarding reserved response
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.421 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 10, Number: 1539
> 2018-05-23 12:07:50.421 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 10, Number: 1800
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.515 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 1800
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.515 Confirming overwriting of file.
> 2018-05-23 12:07:50.515 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 22, Number: 2053
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.890 Status code: 1
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.890 15 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2018-05-23 12:07:50.890 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 10, Number: 4612
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.890 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 17, Number: 3589
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.890 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 17, Number: 3845
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.921 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 17, Number: 4101
< 2018-05-23 12:07:50.921 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 17, Number: 4357
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.921 Preserving timestamp [2018-05-23T16:06:50.000Z]
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.937 Transfer done: '/Inbox/FILENAME.txt' => 'C:\Test\Automation\NewFolder' [163487]
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.937 Copying finished: Transferred: 163,487, Elapsed: 0:00:00, CPS: 493,279/s
> 2018-05-23 12:07:50.937 Script: exit
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.937 Script: Exit code: 0
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.937 Closing connection.
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.937 Sending special code: 12
. 2018-05-23 12:07:50.937 Sent EOF message
```

This line of the log tells me it downloaded, however navigating to the save location shows me an empty folder.

```
  . 2018-05-23 12:07:50.937 Transfer done: '/Inbox/FILENAME.txt' => 'C:\Test\Automation\NewFolder' [163487]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `get` command syntax says: download all files from `/Inbox` to local folder `C:\Test\Automation` and save them to file `NewFolder`. What effectively makes all files overwrite each other. Assuming that `NewFolder` *folder* actually does not exist. Had it existed, the download would fail with *"is not file"* error.

You are also for sure using some rather old version of WinSCP. As recent versions of WinSCP would warn you, that you are probably doing something wrong:

> Are you sure you want to transfer multiple files to a single file 'NewFolder' in a directory 'C:\Test\Automation\'?
>   The files will overwrite one another.
>   If you actually want to transfer all files to a directory 'C:\Test\Automation\NewFolder\', keeping their name, make sure you **terminate the path with a slash**.

See also [documentation for `get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get):

> The last parameter specifies target local directory and optionally operation mask to store file(s) under different name. **Target directory must end with backslash.**

---

Solution:

- Add blackslash;
- Create `NewFolder` folder;
- And you should also upgrade to the latest version of WinSCP.

Comment: Thanks the trailing \ helped but wasn't the main issue. Apparently WinSCP can't handle long paths on the local directory. Changing the path solved the issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `C:\Test\Automation\NewFolder` does not really look like a long path. And [WinSCP supports long local paths](https://winscp.net/tracker/821) anyway, at least with SFTP protocol. And if you are using an old version of WinSCP, which does not support it, you would at least get a corresponding error message.